# QML Virtual keyboard Hide button not working. Again

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, virtual-keyboard

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784405/qml-virtual-keyboard-hide-button-not-working) but it seems rather out-dated since I use Qt 5.14. I have a similar problem.

I set the `visible` property of my `InputPanel` to `active` and tried putting the `TextField` into a `TextInput` but still I cannot hide the keyboard via the close button available in the bottom right corner .

Currently there are two workarounds for me :
1 ) Adding the `onAccepted` signal for any `TextField` or `TextInput` to hide the Virtual keyboard after hitting `Enter` (on Real or virtual keyboard , both works)

2 ) Adding a redundant `Button` to just hide the keyboard

But the clean method for closing it is what a typical user would expect : The specified button in the keyboard

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `InputPanel::active` instead of `Item::visible`?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Do you mean "active: true" ? I tried that. But still the button has no effect.